# SugarCRM - Database Failure - Row Size Too Large?

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

I've been building a custom module for sugarCRM and i'm running into some issue's, when installing the module i'm met with 'Database failure. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details.'

Upon checking the log file, i can find the error is this:

"MySQL error 1118: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
01/03/14"

Whilst my module does have alot of fields, is there anyway i could get around this? Seems like sugar doesn't give me options for varchar/text etc when creating fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran in to this same problem when implementing SugarCRM as a multi-tenant solution. You have a couple of options.

1) Go in to studio and set the size of your fields to a smaller value. Each character in a varchar field is a few bytes in size on average. Therefore, if you reduce the amount of characters allowed for each of your fields in studio you will allow for more fields in your module. (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

2) Divide up those fields into a couple of modules that relate to a parent module. This will spread out your fields over more than 1 table preventing you from hitting the limit.

I would be happy to assist further if you need a more in-depth explanation of either solution.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input.

Sounds like splitting the fields into a few modules might be the best route to go, considering we're looking to future-proof things I'm sure we'll run into the size issue sooner or later other-wise.

If you can point me in the direction of any information or are happy to assist, How would i set up a parent/child module relationship, and get them to behave in the desired way?

Thanks Again!

Comment: Are you on CE or PRO? SugarCRM 6.5 or 7.x? Im going to a shot in the dark and guess Community Edition 6.5. Below is a link to the developer documentation and a youtube video on creating relationships between modules. Other great resources are the sugarCRM forums, and #sugarcrm on freenode (IRC).  - http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Administration_Guide/07_Developer_Tools - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGRlUNvyfgw

Comment: Your shot in the dark was spot on. Thanks for the links, I'll keep you updated :)

Comment: Thanks Man! Making good progress with the split so far, and it does seem to make the whole end user experience much easier! 

I'll drop further comments here should there be any more issues :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Ill keep an eye on the comments.